# In google scholar my book and its 2.5k citations is assigned to the wrong author: what can I do?

Tags: citations, books, google-scholar

In 2008, myself, Bill Langdon and Nic McPhee wrote a book entitled "A field guide to genetic programming". We made it freely available on the internet so as to maximally benefit the field of genetic programming, an area which we collectively had spent something like 50 years researching.

Unfortunately, at some point, in Google Scholar the book has been assigned to a colleague (Michael O'Neill) who kindly wrote a book review for us in the journal of Genetic Programming and Evolvable Machines back in 2009.

Because the book review article was entitled "Riccardo Poli, William B. Langdon, Nicholas F. McPhee: A Field Guide to Genetic Programming" and Michael was listed as the author (of the review article), Google Scholar thinks he is the author of the book and it assigns the 2500+ citations of the book to his profile, bundling all its different citation-versions with the review article.

Michael has been very helpful and has tried twice (once last year, once a week or so ago) to edit the Google Scholar entry for the book (only he can do it, as he believed to be the author), removing/unmerging the book entries from the book review entry. However, nothing seems to happen.

I've tried to find a way to provide feedback to the team in charge of google scholar, but I cannot find how I can inform them of this issue.

So, I am unable to get the book back into my google scholar profile.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding the merged version to your profile (using "Add articles"), and then trying to unmerge it within your profile?

Comment: Many thanks. This fixed the problem

Comment: The comment above and the answer below suggest two different solutions. It would help future readers if you could clarify which worked for you.

Comment: Hi @GoodDeeds, the first part of your answer (Add articles) and the + icon suggested by lordy below (which does the same function) worked. I did not need to unmerge. Many thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add the book manually to your profile? Use the "+"-symbol between "TITLE" and the three dots in the header and then click "Add article manually". Might take a few days until the book shows up in your list.

Comment: Many thanks! This was the solution

Comment: @RiccardoPoli please accept the answer :)